# cpanel user has access to all emails on hosting server

Tags: email, cpanel, vps

I have a VPS with a renowned hosting company. When I log on to cpanel, I can navigate to my VPS directories using the 'File Manager' option in cpanel. This takes me to public_html folder on my VPS, alongside it there is the 'Mail' folder. If I enter the 'Mail' folder, I can read all the emails in the different mailboxes created for employees of the firm. In this scenario, a developer in the firm can log on to the server and read emails from the other employees of the firm.

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: Not sure if this is a "best practices" question or not?  I would take this up with your employer and ultimately this hosting provider.  The question that goes through my mind is that what would you need to do to get to the e-mail for a project they have in mind?  Of course, I would tell your employer of your findings and then determine the best course of action.

Comment: hi, in this case I am the employer and I am also part of the development team. I am in touch with the hosting company but they say there is no solution to this. I find it hard to believe given this is a clear flaw in the default set up

Comment: I am not sure what this has to do with coding or debugging scripts?  I don't think SO is the appropriate place to discuss best practices or how to deal with issues like this.  I am sorry.

Comment: i don't think that SO is limited to only 'coding or debugging scripts'. this question is presenting a technical challenge that am sure many members have faced in web development, hosting, administration especially using cpanel, which is a very popular software.

Comment: I apologize as I am not to debate this issue, but I still feel this falls under #6 of the following page - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .  We can't discuss why or how your provider placed the mails in a folder that is visible to you or anybody else?  This is kind of like why we have 37 admins in our domain and can you comment as to how to address this?  In fact one of the first items that is listed is: "include some of the code you are working with."  We can't discuss why or how something was done.  Technical?  Sure..  How you deal with it is your issue - sorry.

Comment: one potential solution to this is to create a user directly on the VPS to be used for dev work, deployments, support etc. this user can be given to the development team. This ensures that the developers don't get access to the cpanel, they only get access to thee server.